# Django confirm_email and confirm_password are returning None

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a form that looks like this.

```
class MyForm(Form):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=128,
                                 widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
                                     'placeholder': 'First Name',
                                     'class': "form-control"}),)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=128,
                                widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
                                    'placeholder': 'Last Name',
                                    'class': "form-control"}),)

    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=128,
                             widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
                                 'placeholder': 'Email',
                                 'class': "form-control"}),)

    confirm_email = forms.EmailField(max_length=128,
                                     widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
                                         'placeholder': 'Confirm Email',
                                         'class': "form-control"}),)

    password = forms.CharField(max_length=128,
                               widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={
                                   'placeholder': 'Password',
                                   'class': "form-control"}),)

    confirm_password = forms.CharField(max_length=128,
                               widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={
                                   'placeholder': 'Confirm Password',
                                   'class': "form-control"}),)

    def clean_email(self):
        cleaned_data = super(MyForm, self).clean()
        email = cleaned_data.get('email')
        confirm_email = cleaned_data.get('confirm_email')

        if not confirm_email:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Please confirm your email.")

        if email and confirm_email:
            if email != confirm_email:
                raise forms.ValidationError("Emails do not match")
        return confirm_email

    def clean_password(self):
        cleaned_data = super(MyForm, self).clean()

        pwd = cleaned_data.get('password')
        cpwd = cleaned_data.get('confirm_password')

        if not cpwd:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Please Confirm your Password")
        if pwd and cpwd:
            if pwd != cpwd:
                raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords do not match.")  #CNone

        return cpwd

    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.clean_email()
        self.clean_password()
        return super(MyForm, self).clean()
```

Both the `confirm_email` and `confirm_passwor`d fields are returning `None` making the fields impossible to validate. I have very little idea of what could be causing this problem.

I this a problem with my form, or is it more likely a problem with the view or even the template?

Comment: clean() method is unnecessary.. remove it.

Answer (score 1):

```
class MyForm(Form):
    first_name = forms.CharField(
        max_length=128,
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={'placeholder': 'First Name','class': "form-control"}
        ),
    )
    last_name = forms.CharField(
        max_length=128,
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={'placeholder': 'Last Name', 'class': "form-control"}
        ),
    )

    email = forms.EmailField(
        max_length=128,                 
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={'placeholder': 'Email', 'class': "form-control"}
        ),
    )

    confirm_email = forms.EmailField(
        max_length=128,
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={'placeholder': 'Confirm Email', n'class': "form-control"}
        ),
    )

    password = forms.CharField(
        max_length=128,
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(
            attrs={'placeholder': 'Password', 'class': "form-control"}
        ),
    )

    confirm_password = forms.CharField(
        max_length=128,
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(
            attrs={'placeholder': 'Confirm Password', 'class': "form-control"}
        ),
    )

    def clean_email(self):
        cdata = self.cleaned_data

        email = cdata['email']
        confirm_email = cdata.['confirm_email']

        if email and confirm_email:
            if email != confirm_email:
                raise forms.ValidationError("Emails do not match")

        return email

    def clean_confirm_email(self):
        cdata = self.cleaned_data

        confirm_email = cdata['confirm_email']

        if not confirm_email:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Please confirm your email.")

        return confirm_email

    def clean_password(self):
        cdata = self.cleaned_data

        password = cdata['password']
        confirm_password = cdata['confirm_password']

        if password and confirm_password:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords do not match.")  

        return password

    def clean_confirm_password(self):
        cdata = self.cleaned_data

        confirm_password = cdata['confirm_password']

        if not confirm_password:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Please Confirm your Password")

        return confirm_password
```

Comment: The error persists. With this configuration, there is no `ValidationError` raised when the emails do not match either.